# Create new column with an index based on column with dates in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pgadmin

EDIT: Indeed, order was wrong.

I'm pretty new to SQL and I use pgAdminIII for it. In our DB we store reports with different dates. For every person we have around 10 reports. In order to compare only the latest or second latest reports of each person, I want to add a column which specifies whether it is the latest. It looks like this(simplified) and the index column is the one I want to create.

```
PersonID Date     Index
A       2013Q4   3
A       2014Q1   2
A       2014Q2   1
B       2013Q4   2
B       2014Q1   1
B       2013Q2   3
C       2013Q1   5   
C       2013Q3   3
C       2013Q2   4
C       2013Q4   2
C       2014Q1   1


> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW My.db AS    
>     a."Date", 
>     a."PersonID",  
   FROM my.db a;
```

I already tried some index functions, but they did not work:

```
INDEX(a."PersonID", a."Date") AS "Index",
```

and

```
CAST
 INDEX(a."PersonID", a."Date") END AS Index,
```

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: You should learn some decent SQL or you will end up with many more such questions. What you need here is `CREATE INDEX`. Look it up in the PG documentation.

Comment: @Patrick - I don't think he is looking for "CREATE INDEX", but I'm not clear on what the "INDEX" function is supposed to be doing. I think it's some sort of "age" of the row, but the ordering doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Richard, The order was indeed a mistake from my side. It is now correct. The INDEX function should rank each PersonID by date. So the latest should have rank 1, so that is a sort of age of the row. This function is used in Tableau which often uses the same code as pg. http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/v8.1/pro/online/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I've tweaked the column-names. Top tip - don't use SQL language words for column-names (date, int, text, table, index etc).

You want a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) - which views a "window" over the whole result-set. In this case you will want `row_number` partitioned over the `person_id` (so it resets when the person changes) and ordered by the `report_date`. The second example reverses the ordering.

```
richardh=> SELECT person_id,report_date,row_number() over (partition by person_id order by report_date)  FROM t1 ORDER BY person_id, report_date;
 person_id | report_date | row_number 
-----------+-------------+------------
 A         | 2013Q2      |          1
 A         | 2013Q3      |          2
 A         | 2013Q4      |          3
 B         | 2013Q1      |          1
 B         | 2013Q2      |          2
 B         | 2013Q3      |          3
 B         | 2013Q4      |          4
 C         | 2013Q3      |          1
 C         | 2013Q4      |          2
 D         | 2013Q1      |          1
 D         | 2013Q2      |          2
 D         | 2013Q4      |          3
(12 rows)

richardh=> SELECT person_id,report_date,row_number() over (partition by person_id order by report_date desc)  FROM t1 ORDER BY person_id, report_date;
 person_id | report_date | row_number 
-----------+-------------+------------
 A         | 2013Q2      |          3
 A         | 2013Q3      |          2
 A         | 2013Q4      |          1
 B         | 2013Q1      |          4
 B         | 2013Q2      |          3
 B         | 2013Q3      |          2
 B         | 2013Q4      |          1
 C         | 2013Q3      |          2
 C         | 2013Q4      |          1
 D         | 2013Q1      |          3
 D         | 2013Q2      |          2
 D         | 2013Q4      |          1
(12 rows)
```